# How to create optional parameters on Swift struct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to build a struct for an input filed that has optional icons.

If an icon name is passed in as a param then it will load, else it will not.

I am getting the error `Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'isEmpty' of wrapped base type 'String'` which I do not understand.

Also, when I initialize the struct it is still requiring the params despite the optional ? indicator. [image]

Comment: Please include code, not pictures of code, which can't be copied/pasted, searched, or read by screen readers.

Comment: try `if preIcon != nil` ... or `if let icon = preIcon`

Comment: There are multiple ways: Optional binding (`if let`), an explicit `init` method with default parameter values or non-optional `var`iables with default empty string values which indicate *no image*. Just calling `isEmpty` on an optional is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the if statement to this

`if preIcon?.isEmpty == false`

Then change

`var preIcon: String?`

`var postIcon: String?`

Comment: This cleared the `Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'isEmpty' of wrapped base type 'String'` error. 

Still getting `Missing arguments for parameters 'preIcon', 'postIcon' in call` when I try to init the struct.`

Comment: Changed `let` to `var` for those two variables. Check the update.

Comment: That did it.  Do you know why the use of "let" prevents the param from being optional?

Comment: If it’s set to let then it has to be set at init. And can’t be changed. Let us for constants, var is for variables.

Comment: Ah, at the time a concrete instance of this struct (aka fancy class) is instatiated (aka init) constants must have a value assigned to them.  That makes sense.  Coming from .JS world and new to swift. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since `preIcon` is an optional, you have to unwrap it before you can access properties on it. So, your line will need to be:

```
if let preIcon = preIcon, !preIcon.isEmpty {
```

You can learn more about optional binding (the `if let` syntax used above) at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

---

In terms of the `struct` requiring properties marked as optionals, although Xcode may include the optional properties in autocomplete, it doesn't actually require that you include values for them -- they can be deleted an your initializer will still work.